# Can't figure out how to count total friends in facebook php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am struggling with counting total friends count of a user and store it in the database. I have this following code:

```
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'ap id','secret key' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mykadamtala.com/facebook/fbconfig.php' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
 $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name');
        $firstname = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
        $lastname = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
        $gender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender');
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');
       $friend_count = ????//how i can get total friends counts of the signed up users?

    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;  
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;

      //storing values to the database. Here i want to store the friend count
        checkuser($fbid,$firstname, $lastname, $femail, $check, $friend_count); 
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope' => 'email'
  ));
  header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

I want to store the total number of friends of a user in a variable called `$friend_count` so i can save the total number in my database.

Searching here i get this

```
$userfriends = $facebook->api('/XXXXXXX152466/friends');
$friend_count =  COUNT($userfriends['data']) + 1;
```

So, if i pass $fbid variable in `api()` will it count total number of friends? Or should i use `taggable_friend` when creating FacebookRequest class instance? I am confused pluggint this into my script. Gracious help will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/me/friends` endpoint, and var_dump the result. You will find `total_friends` in it, with the total number of friends. You can read more about it in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_new_features

Comment: @lushchn thank you for your reply. so i have to use $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' ); but if i pass friends, the grahpObject will still return other data? id, email, fullname? or should i have to mention all data i want to retrieve? `me?fields=name, gender, friends` this way?

Comment: you want the number of friends, not their data. that´s what i can read from your question. as i said, just use /me/friends without any parameters and there will be a count in the result. just debug id.

Comment: and PLEASE don´t ask how to get all friends data, because it is explained in hundres of stackoverflow questions that you can only get data of friends who authorized your app too ;) - you can only get the total count.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `getDecodedBody` method.

Like that:

```
// Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
try {
    $response = Facebook::get('/me?fields=friends');
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
}

return $response->getDecodedBody();
```

If you convert the response to Json, should return:

```
{
    friends: {
        data: [ ],
        summary: {
            total_count: 1187
        }
    },
    id: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```